# How to un-hide the read recipient (blue tick) option on WhatsApp?

Tags: whatsapp-messenger

How to un-hide the read recipient (blue tick) option on WhatsApp? I am not able to find the option.

Answer (score 1):

1. Open WhatsApp and tap three vertical dots icon on the top right.
2. Now go to **Settings > Account > Privacy**.
3. Check Read receipts.

Comment: Thanks but now i can't show other persons blue sticks ?
What's the matter ?

Comment: You can only see Double Tick if others can see your Double Tick. Its same like hiding Last Seen, when you do it, you cant see others Last Seen as well.....

Comment: It's not good man !!

Comment: Lol. thats just how it is. If i have answered your question please consider accepting the answer if you wish.

Comment: Lol. thats just how it is. If i have answered your question please consider accepting the answer if you wish.

Comment: :D, I could understand you :)